# guild.member.hasPermission is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was rummaging through an old source of discord.js from v11, and merged most of it to v12, mind you this script is erroring within the `ready` event, I'd prefer not to put it elsewhere.

This is what I have for now:

```js
client.on('ready', async () => {
  log.success(`Authenticated as ${client.user.tag}`);
  client.user.setPresence({
    activity: {
      name: env.PRESENCE_ACTIVITY,
      type: env.PRESENCE_TYPE.toUpperCase(),
    },
  });
  const guild = client.guilds.cache.find((g) => g.id === '000000000');

  if (!guild)
    return console.log(`Can't find any guild with the ID "${env.GUILD_ID}"`);

  if (guild.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR', false)) {
    log.success("Bot has the 'ADMINISTRATOR' permission");
  } else 
    log.warn("Bot does not have 'ADMINISTRATOR' permission");

  client.guilds.cache
    .get(env.GUILD_ID)
    .roles.fetch()
    .then((roles) => {
      goodieRole = roles.cache.get(env.GOODIE_ROLE_ID);
    });
});
```

Comment: what's the output of guild?

Comment: @Spidy my ID was returning as a snowflake, turned it into a string and that is the error I receive now

Comment: @CherryDT will check it out now

Comment: @CherryDT not at all, I'm not calling the message event, this is running on the ready event. Which is why I'm trying to call it this way

Comment: What do you think `guild.member` is? Or what do you expect it to be?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros To reference, it was supposed to be wrapped in a `.fetch` however, I didn't have a clue on doing that as I'm new to d.js, but I have minimal js knowledge and LUA knowledge

Comment: guild.member.hasPermission is not a function.. anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @CherryDT, it's not a duplicate. OP is using discord.js v12, which still has the `hasPermission()` method, so it should be not closed as a dupe.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `member` property on `guild`s. If you want to get the bot as a member of that `guild`, you can [`fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v12/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) them from [`guild.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v12/class/Guild?scrollTo=members). If you're using discord.js v12, you can use the [`hasPermission()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v12/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=hasPermission) method to check if the bot has an [`ADMINISTRATOR` flag](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v12/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS):

```js
client.on('ready', async () => {
  log.success(`Authenticated as ${client.user.tag}`);
  client.user.setPresence({
    activity: {
      name: env.PRESENCE_ACTIVITY,
      type: env.PRESENCE_TYPE.toUpperCase(),
    },
  });
  const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(env.GUILD_ID);

  if (!guild)
    return console.log(`Can't find any guild with the ID "${env.GUILD_ID}"`);

  let botMember = await guild.members.fetch(client.user);

  if (botMember.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR', false)) {
    log.success("Bot has the 'ADMINISTRATOR' permission");
  } else
    log.warn("Bot does not have 'ADMINISTRATOR' permission");
  
  // ...
```

Comment: It seems as if it just barely worked, it returned an undefined error on roles via .roles.fetch()

Comment: It seems like a different issue. My answer solves the original question and if my answer solved the original question, you can upvote and accept it. You should not edit your question and create a completely new one in an edit. If you have a new issue, you should make a [new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). I'm trying to help with that one too.

Comment: Ahh, I see. My apologies as I'm new here. However it's back to saying hasPermission isn't a function. I'll go back to using botmember, however no fix yet.

Comment: This actually fixed it, thanks. Unsure of what I did

Comment: No worries, I edited your question, so it's back to normal again :)